# switch checkbox not checked after opening the document again

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, react-hooks, checkbox

I am new to React & I have a bootstrap switch checkbox and for me the value is getting saved in the mongodb but my problem is when I open the document again, the checkbox is not in the position where it was last updated.

If I updated the document while it is true it wont be

[image]

The code is below:

```
  const [flag, setFlag] = useState(false);
  
  const checkHandler = () => {
    setFlag(!flag);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (order) {
      console.log("order is present in empty useEffect", order);
      setFlag(order.flag);
    }
  }, [order]);
```

```
<div className="flagOrder">
                    <div class="form-check form-switch">
                      <input
                        class="form-check-input"
                        type="checkbox"
                        role="switch"
                        id="flexSwitchCheckDefault"
                        checked={flag}
                        onChange={checkHandler}
                      />
                      <label
                        class="form-check-label"
                        for="flexSwitchCheckDefault"
                      >
                        Flag
                      </label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
```

The below function runs when update order button is clicked on page

```html
const updateOrder = (order, items) => {
    console.log("ofasdfrder in update order", order);
    const updatedata = {
      _id: order._id,
      items: items,
      customerNotes:
        newCustomerNote.length > 0
          ? [...customerNotes, { notes: newCustomerNote, user: user._id }]
          : customerNotes,
      internalNotes:
        newInternalNote.length > 0
          ? [...internalNotes, { notes: newInternalNote, user: user._id }]
          : internalNotes,
      paymentMade: partialPaymentMade,
      newCustomerNote: newCustomerNote,
      newInternalNote: newInternalNote,
      paymentStatus: paymentStatus,
      changePaymentStatus:
        originalPaymentStatus === paymentStatus ? true : false,
      sendToCustomerNotes: sendToCustomerNotes,
      sendToInternalNotes: sendToInternalNotes,
      subTotal: getSubTotal(items).toFixed(2),
      totalAmount: (
        getSubTotal(items) +
        getTax(items) +
        getShipping(items)
      ).toFixed(2),
      shippingTotal: order ? getShipping(items) : 0,
      taxTotal: getTax(items),
      orderStatus: orderStatus,
      flag: flag,
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to check the value stored in mongoDB on page load to check the state of checkbox. if it is missing there, load the default state.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).